# importKey alg RSA-OAEP with SHA-1 not working on safari 11

Tags: cryptography, rsa, webcrypto-api

The problem with key operation appears on Outlook for mac and on Safari 11 . When I try on Chrome/Firefox on mac it's work well.

I use webCrypto library of js :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API

And in addition another library of crypto that need to fix the problems on safari :
https://github.com/vibornoff/webcrypto-shim

It’s stuck in level of ‘importKey’ function:

```
                    window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
                    "jwk",
                    {
                        "kty": "RSA",
                        "e": E VALUE,
                        "n": N VALUE,
                        "alg": "RSA-OAEP",
                        "ext": true
                    },
                    {
                        name: "RSA-OAEP",
                        hash: { name: "SHA-1" },
                    },
                    true, 
                    ["encrypt"]
                    ).then(function (publicKey) { })
```

The error I get:
 **OpeartionTypeError :Member JsonWebKey.kty is required and must be an instance of DOMString .**

I read this question : [Safari WebCrypto API RSA-OAEP encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798241/safari-webcrypto-api-rsa-oaep-encryption) and the solution accepted  using ‘RSA-OAEP’ alg and hash of ‘SHA-1’ but I get always same error not matter what I try to change.

I am not sure that all the others functions of webcrypto work on safari 11 but right not I stuck on this .

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We have created a shim layer called https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto-liner that unifies behaviors for the various browsers and provides JS implementations for downlevel browsers.

You can use https://peculiarventures.github.io/pv-webcrypto-tests/ to test the expected support for each browser both with and without this plug-in.

With that said, on Safari 11.0 (13604.1.38.1.6), I seem to be able to import RSA-OAEP /w SHA1 without the use of that shim layer.

Without a more complete example of what your doing (sample values and browser build versions) I don't think I or anyone else will be able to help much.

Comment: Thanks for your help ,  great library good work.What the different between your library to  'webcrypto-shim' library ? About my case ,suddenly the original code working on safari , strange behavior after it's doesn't work for a while .

Comment: `webcrypto-shim` tries to normalize behavior in some narrow cases only, mine does this and adds support where algorithms are not present. As for random behavior of your code, sorry can't help without more data.

Comment: I've just tried webcrypto-liner because I couldn't get PBKDF2 to work on Safari. But after stupidly trying to get it to work for a while, I found out that webcrypto-liner can't help with this issue, and the documentation also says it doesn't work. This is really depressing. It's kind of weird, because Webkit clearly has this feature https://webkit.org/blog/7790/update-on-web-cryptography/ Does this mean it is 100% impossible to do any sort of key derivation on Safari? (Which means I can't do this on iOS either)

Comment: Vlad, we did not implement PBKDF2 in liner, though it would be possible to add it. Safari 11 is able to do PBDKF2 import, deriveKey and deriveBits but not generate key. At least on Safari desktop.